# Cannot retain keyboard in titanium textfield

Tags: titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I am new to Appcelerator and I am tasked with migrating Titanium code to use latest SDK and I am facing issues with keyboard. When I edit a textfield, keyboard closes for every selection whereas I would like to retain it until I press "return" or "Done" button. Ay ideas how I can do this? Appreciate any help in this regards.

Thank you.

Comment: Show us the code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to figure out the problem. The height property for text field was set to 'Auto' which was causing the issue. I set it to a numeric value and the issue is resolved.